# Can Gramex scheduler take dynamic schedule values from a file or database?

Tags: gramex

Trying to run some CLI on schedule like

```yaml
create-job-once-a-day:
  hours: <DYNAMIC VALUE>
  minutes: <DYNAMIC VALUE>
  thread: true
  function: >
    logging.critical('HELLO')
```

Is It possible to take the DYNAMIC VALUES from dynamic sources like a file?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to run every minute, and check the time (or for any condition) in the `function`. For example:

```yaml
create-job-once-a-day:
  hours: '*'
  minutes: '*'
  thread: true
  function: >
    mymodule.my_schedule_function()
```

In `mymodule.py`:

```py
def my_schedule_function():
    if some_dynamic_condition_is_true():
        logging.critical('HELLO')
        # perform rest of the task
```

Schedules are quite efficient, so this won't impact the CPU.